# Insufficient privileges to operate on 'SYSTEM' running SHOW ORGANIZATION ACCOUNTS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to snowflake and trying to read through all the documentation.  One of the subjects was account identifiers and provided SQL to show organization accounts.  When trying to execute this under the ACCOUNTADMIN role, I receive the following error.

```
SHOW ORGANIZATION ACCOUNTS
```

> SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on
> 'SYSTEM'

If account admin is the most powerful account, what else might be happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute this command as an ORGADMIN. Only organization administrators (users with the ORGADMIN role) can execute this SQL command.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-organization-accounts.html#usage-notes

Enabling the ORGADMIN role

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-gs.html#enabling-the-orgadmin-role-for-an-account

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-gs.html#assigning-the-orgadmin-role-to-a-user-or-role

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations.html#orgadmin-role

Answer (score 1):

ACCOUNTADMIN is the highest privileged role in an account but Organisation is a level above accounts. Firstly you would need to be set up to use Organisations and then you would need to use the ORGADMIN role to run Organisation-level queries

Answer (score 1):

Please run below statement to grant ORGADMIN role in your account. This will allow you to use Organizations feature.

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
grant role orgadmin to user <username>;--Run with accountadmin role
```

Or

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
grant role orgadmin to role <non-systemroles>;--Run with accountadmin role
```

Doc link: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide-organizations.html